# Como colocar uma linha a separar items de um menu?

Tags: android

Olá,
alguém sabe como posso colocar uma linha horizontal para separar os items do meu menu sem ter de utilizar a tag `<group>`?
Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<menu>

<item android:id="@+id/action_rate"
    android:title="@string/action_rate"
    android:orderInCategory="100"/>


<item android:id="@+id/action_comment"
    android:title="@string/action_comment"
    android:orderInCategory="100"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tente isso entre os itens:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_gray2"
        android:focusable="false" />
```

Comment: Não funcionou :\

Comment: mudou a cor? talvez a cor dark_gray não esteja no tema que você está utilizando

Comment: Sim mudei, foi na primeira coisa que reparei.

Comment: Utilize o atributo com a cor embarcada _android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"_ que vai funcionar sem problemas.

Answer (score 3):

alternativamente também pode usar as ferramentas de prototipagem gráfica do Android Studio, disponíveis no menu design, ou se preferir, important um framework como bootstrap e tirar de lá os elementos que pretende. existe uma boa biblioteca para esse tipo de coisas, disponível em: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Comment: Valeu pela dica! +1